SQLAlchemy: How to get only the columns I need from a child element during a query execution with JOIN?
I have some SQLAlchemy models for example:
    class Objects(Base):
        __tablename__ = "objects"
  
        id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        type: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
        name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(VARCHAR(128), nullable=False)
        device: Mapped["Devices"] = relationship(back_populates="object")

    class Devices(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'devices'

        id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('objects.id'), primary_key=True)
        settings: Mapped[dict] = mapped_column(JSONB)
        state: Mapped[dict] = mapped_column(JSONB)
        type: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
        object: Mapped["Objects"] = relationship(back_populates="device")


So, this is one-to-one relation. In Devices I store more concretly data about device. I need to get full info from Objects and only state from Devices. Thats not trouble. The problem is that i want to access result like this:
    res.id - Objects.id
    res.device.state - Devices.state
    res.type - Objects.type

...
But query gives me tuple of (Objects, Devices.state). If i try joinedload or subqueryload - i`m getting not only state from DB, but settings too, I dont need them. So, help me please with sqlalchemy query, I dont know what to do.
What I want:
    result: {
        "id": Objects.id,
        "type": Objects.type,
        "name": Objects.name,
        "device": {
            "state": Devices.state (Objects.device.state),
            "settings": None,
            "type": None,
            ...
        }
    }

What I have:
    result: ( 
        {  
            "id": Objects.id,
            "type": Objects.type,
            "name": Objects.name
        }, 
        Devices.state
    )

What i did:
    sql = (
        select(Objects, Devices.state.label("device_state"))
        .join(Devices)
        .filter(Objects.id == device_id)
    )
    sql = (
        select(Objects, Devices.state)
        .join_from(Objects, Devices)
        .filter(Objects.id == device_id)
    )

And many other attemptions, which i`ve deleted)

Use load_only() with either:
using-load-only-with-multiple-entities or using-load-only-on-related-objects-and-collections
Probably like this (Devices.id is also loaded):
sql = select(Objects).options(joinedload(Objects.device).load_only(Devices.state))


Result of this is Row[tuple[Objects, Devices]] and there`s no device, I want Row[tuple[Objects]]
To get state i need to gow res[1].state
But i want to get state by res.device.state

I updated the query.
